# Div bg not matching up with Body bg

Tags: html, css

I have a website that completes the layout by joining body tag's bg and div tags' bgs. However, depending on the browser and OS you're using, they don't seem to match accurately due to the scrollbar. (I have tested by adding overflow:hidden; to the body element and everything matched perfectly)

Is there any way of fixing this?

The gap is as small as this:

[image]

```
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="contentL>
...
</div>
<div id="contentR">
...
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>

body{ background:url('bg.jpg') top center no-repeat #000; }
#content{ width:980px; margin:0 auto; }
#contentL{ width:220px; padding:20px; float:left; background:url('left.jpg'); }
#contentR{ width:680px; padding:20px; float:right; background:url('right.jpg'); }
```

Thanks

Comment: hi can you more specific about your problem?

Comment: Is your HTML valid? If not, you might trigger quirks-mode in the browser and thus get unexpected results. Other than that, the provided code and the image aren't that helpful, instead provide a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean that you're getting a gap in between the two inner content `div`s when using IE. If so this is due to the difference in the box model between IE and other browsers - IE includes your padding inside the width while other browsers add it to the outside of the width.

So your fix is to remove the padding. But maybe you still want some separation between the contents of those `div`s. For this you can add another div inside your content L & R `div`s which then have padding on them - don't put specific widths on those inner `div`s because then you have the same issue but just make sure they are display block, that is how they'll take up the available width with the padding inside the width in all browsers.

This is how I do it but there may be better ways including ie specific style sheets and the box model hack - just Google for info on the box model and dealing with IE.